# Javascript - make function return unique result for every div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need this function to run on a variable amount of divs and return a unique result for each div.

```
class Sentence {
    constructor(na, num, col) {
        this.name = na;
        this.number = num;
        this.color = col;
    }

    makesentence() {
        $('div').html(this.name + " is " + this.number + " years old and loves " + this.color);
    }
}



var names = ['zach', 'kelly', 'lisa', 'slater'],
    name = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)],
    colors = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'magenta'],
    color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
    number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 95) + 1);



var newsentence = new Sentence(name, number, color);
newsentence.makesentence();
```

So, if my HTML is 3 empty divs:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**I would like it to return something like:**
lisa is 67 years old and loves red
zach is 56 years old and loves magenta
kelly is 27 years old and loves orange

**But now it just returns something like:**
lisa is 67 years old and loves red
lisa is 67 years old and loves red
lisa is 67 years old and loves red

Comment: You are picking a random name *once*. You are picking a random color *once*. If you want random results more than once, you need to call `Math.random()` more than once. You're also changing the text of every single div in one go. Having not just random() but unique results is actually simpler here: it means you just need to shuffle your arrays randomly, then compose the div texts in order. I'd also refrain from using classes until you have a firm grasp of the more basic stuff.

Comment: My take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/trgo7mw5/ (not going to try and score cheap points on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this can be achieved quite easily by reogranising your code around the iteration over `<div>` elements in your document.

As a stratergy to gurantee unique results for each div, you could shuffle your input data like so:

```
 names = names.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
 colors = colors.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
 ages = ages.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
```

And then iterate over each `<div>`, populating the contents of each sequentially via each element's `index` in this way:

```
$('div').each(function(index) {

  var name = names[index];
  var color = colors[index];
  var number = ages[index];

  $(this).html(name + " is " + number + " years old and loves " + color);
});
```

The idea here is to first shuffle your input data (ie to achieve the randomised result) followed by ordered access to that data when generating your sentences, which ensures uniqueness between sentenses in the final result.

Here's a working snippet showing the two ideas in action:

```js
// Declare input data to be used for sentense generation. 
// Also declare age data array
var names = ['zach', 'kelly', 'lisa', 'slater'];
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'magenta'];
var ages = new Array(100).fill(0).map((value, index) => index + 1);

// Shuffle the input data to yield a randomized result
names = names.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
colors = colors.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
ages = ages.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });

// Iterate over each div in the document
$('div').each(function(index) {
  
  // Get data from each array by current div's index
  var name = names[index];
  var color = colors[index];
  var number = ages[index];
  
  // For the current div, update the html content as before
  $(this).html(name + " is " + number + " years old and loves " + color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @ChrisG ah forgot that - thanks for spotting my error :)

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why the answers have to be so complicated when a simple each loop thru each div would do the work just fine.

```
$.each($(".div"), function(){
  var names = ['zach', 'kelly', 'lisa', 'slater'],
  name = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)],
  colors = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'magenta'],
  color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
  number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 95) + 1);

  var newsentence = new Sentence(name, number, color);

  $(this).html(newsentence.makesentence());
});
```

You can add a condition if you want the result to be even more unique as you mentioned.

Comment: what is the $.each doing here? I'm not familiar with this syntax of $.functionname,i would think you need to to specify an element to run the function on? like $('element').functionname?